# Python to read wsdl not working

Tags: python, wsdl

I am trying this code to fetch data from wsdl.

Querying the website for the zipid("60630") works fine but in my code it gives the error as

"Invalid ZIP"

```
wsdlFile = 'http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl'
wsdlObject = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlFile)
wsdlObject.show_methods()
zipid = "60630"
result = wsdlObject.GetCityWeatherByZIP(ZIP=zipid)
print result[1]
```

Can someone please help whats wrong here and why the code is not working correctly.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that your client sends a request the server doesn't understand. Seems you're using `SOAPpy`, that's the request it sends when I try it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<GetCityWeatherByZIP SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<v1 xsi:type="xsd:string">60630</v1>
</GetCityWeatherByZIP>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In comprison when using [`suds`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.4.1.jurko.4):

```
from suds.client import Client
cli = Client("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl")
cli.service.GetCityWeatherByZIP(ZIP=60630)
```

it produces:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <ns1:Body>
    <ns0:GetCityWeatherByZIP>
      <ns0:ZIP>60630</ns0:ZIP>
    </ns0:GetCityWeatherByZIP>
  </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

(captured using wireshark)

The second request returns a valid result from the server.

I don't know SOAPpy well enough to suggest a way to fix this, but maybe you could consider switching your client library to suds.